# How do I Split up batch OData requests

Tags: sapui5

I'm using 'batch' OData requests. However, two separate entity reads are being called in the same request.

How do I split these up into 2 separate batch requests?

E.g.

```js
surveyModel.read("/ResultOfflineSet", {
  filters: [
    new Filter("QuestionId", FilterOperator.EQ, questionId),
    new Filter("JobId", FilterOperator.EQ, self.jobId)
  ],
  success: function(oData, oResponse) {
    resolve(oData);
  },
  error: function (oError) {
    reject(false);
  }
});
```

Then later..

```js
// Retreive Category Info and set up panel info.
_.each(oViewData.categories, function(result, index) {
  surveyModelCat.read("/CategorySet", {
    filters: [
      new Filter("CategoryId", FilterOperator.EQ, index)
    ],
    success: function(oDataCategory) {
      oViewData.categories[index].categoryId = oDataCategory.results[0].CategoryId;
      oViewData.categories[index].categoryDesc = oDataCategory.results[0].CategoryDesc;
      oViewData.categories[index].expanded = false;
      oViewData.categories[index].complete = false;
      oViewModel.setData(oViewData);
      resolve(oDataCategory);
    },
    error: function(oError) {
      self.getView().byId("Page1").setVisible(true);
      self.busyDialog.close();
    }
  });
});
```

When running the app and viewing the Network tab in Chrome, I can see the calls for `resultOfflineSet` and `CategorySet` as part of the same `$batch` request.

Why aren't they in two separate $batches?

Comment: Typically the GET requests are bundled together in a $batch request since they should have no side effects. Do you want to separate them due to performance reasons?

Comment: Yes sort of. I'm having memory issues so just wanted to rule it out.

Comment: You can also disable batch requests altogether, but that doesn't help you either, right?

Comment: No, because that changes the sequence of events in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are two things you can try. First the oData model has a setting called `useBatch` which can be set to false. Otherwise at the end of the read the oData model has a `submitBatchRequests` method that can be called which would force flush all pending requests that were to be batched together. Either of these should solve the problem.

Comment: Can you give me an example of submitBatchRequests.  I've tried it to no avail.....